# JAAS : on Callback ( Interesting based on HTTP headers )

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jaas

I am using NameCallback and PasswordCallback for username and password.For username and password, popup comes on browser and when i enter username ans password, JAAS authenticates my request.

On the wireshark, I have seen that 401 Unauthorized message (WWW-Authenticate header)comes and when i enter username/password HTTP request with credentials generate ( with Authorization header) and goes to server.

**My requirement :** I don't want pop up to come.My application on other server having username / password, so once it received 401 then based on some logic it will generate HTTP request with Authorization header / credentials  and sent it back.

**FLow :**  User -> Other Server -> My Tomcat5.5

Here on Other Server, nobody is available to enter username/password manually.Application is deployed and it will only generate HTTP request with credential and sent it back to tomcat.

Can we have any other callback which behave like this.Need your help.Please provide me feedback as well related to approach.

**Edit Question :**

Here is the actual case :

UserA made a call ( SIP Protocol ) to XYZ server.Application deployed on XYZ server create a HTTP REST request and sent it to Tomcat Server where One application is deployed in order to get some user account detail.Once the HTTP request comes to the tomcat, I ll have to authenticate it.I am using JAASRealm implementation of tomcat.

Now for authentication, what tomcat is doing, it pop up the username/password window at XYZ server.At XYZ server, as application had created HTTP request, so no one is here to enter username/ password manually ( as this does not goes to User A device).

I am looking a way where this pop up does not comes, and application deployed in XYZ server should do something like :

if(response equal 401) then
create HTTP request with credential.

So i was looking for a soulution where pop up does not comes.Is it clear now,Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Your application should use a java.net.Authenticator to supply the credentials to HttpURLConnection, rather than dealing directly with 401 and WWW-Authenticate headers.

Comment: Kudos for being able to decrypt the completely confusing question.

Comment: @EJP : Thanks...Actually I am using JAASRealm based implementation of tomcat5.5.....As far as the application part...i am fine with your comment...got the point...One one thing I would like to ask, Is their any way to stop the popup coming for the username / password...

Comment: @VJS The popup only happens in browsers, in response to a 401. There is no way that whatever you are logging into can show a popup to your HTTP client, because your HTTP client isn't a browser. Are you referring to what happens if a *user* tries to view the same page? Your question remains completely confusing: I agree entirely with BalusC; and instead of shooting the messenger, what you should be concerned with is making your question more comprehensible, so you are more likely to get answers.

Comment: @VJS You *are* trying it with an HTTP client. Java is an HTTP client. Re BalusC, you can continue to shoot the messenger, but the only thing of note here is that even after two people have told you your question is completely confusing, you still have made *zero attempt* to clarify it.

Comment: @EJP : Please have a look again.I have mentioned scenario.I was really worried while posting..Let me know if its clear now.

Comment: @VJS I repeat. Browsers popup dialog windows. Tomcat doesn't popup dialog windows, at XYZ or anywhere else. Unless you have coded that into your application. In which case, the answer is 'don't'.